# Toyota camry 2003 , 2azfe - 2.4 L , vibrates at idling & does not accelerate properly

Tags: engine, toyota, camry, idle, vibration

Recently I sent my Camry to the workshop as there was a blown water outlet pipe, and was told that the head gasket was damaged too. These were then replaced, and I took delivery of my car. But my problem seem to have increased as now the car/engine vibrates on idle when in neutral, and sometimes the rev goes below 500 rpm (that too while driving) and the engine dies.

Before sending it to the workshop, my car used to accelerate very well and was fun to drive, but now, there are times that there is no proper pickup/acceleration, and sometimes it just gets to normal all by itself. The garage is not able to solve this for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to check would be that the engine and hoses were put back together properly. If the engine loses vacuum, it can cause rough idling. In such a case, though, the car would usually run well at speed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Lexus ES350. Check the spark plugs, fuel filters and air filters . Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best starting point is to check for any fault codes. If you want to DIY, you can purchase an ODB2 code reader yourself. However, a good mechanic will have more sophisticated diagnostic equipment, which will make it easier to isolate the problem.

There are many parts to be reinstalled after a head gasket replacement, so there are many possible causes of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have power and everything else works fine accept your Acceleration:  I would take this to be a **dirty Throttle Body Unit** or a failed **Throttle Position Sensor**  and your **Mas Air Flow Sensor.**  Now for vibration issues I would check your Fast Idle Air Control Valve.